# Call a function when user press a Key from Keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I call a function when the user presses a key from the keyboard ?

This is for Desktop development .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Actions and shortcuts in flutter. These widgets work something like this :

[image: How actions and shortcuts work]

To get a more detailed information, please refer to the flutter docs [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/actions_and_shortcuts). These come under Advanced UI concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're using a TextField? It has the following property `onChanged: ((newText) => {})`

You can go ahead and use it like this:

```
onChanged: ((newText) => { yourFunction; }),
```

or

```
onChanged: ((newText) => { setState((){yourFunction;}); }),
```

**Just to clarify, this will only update when the text changes. @Divyam Dhadwal seems to have a wild answer that might be more useful**

Good luck my man! xx

Comment: Thank you for your time . but i'm not using a textfield. I have a function that will show a message when he presses (ie: the button 'x' from his keyboard)

Comment: Misunderstood the question, sorry! Appreciate the comment, thank you xx